# is it okay to take a vacation in the first year of a new job?

Tags: new-job, vacation

Is it okay to take a vacation in the first year of a new job?

I just landed a new job as a Software Development Engineer II in a test engineering department I am filling one of three seats. I have a few vacations lined up that my new managers knew about as the interviewing process came to an end. the following vacations however are not any of them and are in planning stages.

So, I was working setting some plans to travel to Egypt in November or December that I have since getting this job decided to shelve for the time being. However, I have Brazilian friends who are really interested in meeting up with me in February for carnival, and plans that are not 100% set in stone to hike the Inca trail in Peru with buddy of mine, and going to Australia next may for my birthday. all of these are within the first year of me being employed.

While I know excessive travel can be a little off putting I am just curious about the general feeling employers have about traveling at all during the first year of a new job?

P.S. Not all of the above listed are going to happen. I think its too much. Also I work in the USA.

Comment: i saw that one and i dont feel it is the same question. i have 4 or 5 different vacations planned. she has one.

Comment: Voting to close, this is company /leave specific.  If you have enough leave over the year go ahead, if not choose what you can do.  As regards taking any time off only you can judge your employer, if they're good they'll realise good workers need RnR, if they're bad it'll be an issue, no one can give a blanket answer.

Comment: fair enough this can be closed i guess.

Comment: Remember, you're entitled to your vacation time. Your employer offered you that benefit in lieu of increased salary. While it's your responsibility to make sure your vacations are scheduled in a way that doesn't adversely impact your team (such as right before a huge product launch), you should not feel guilty over taking it.

Comment: Don't you just have a fixed number of days' leave per year? i.e. that you can schedule with your boss?

Comment: exactly, the best thing to do is get approval as early as you can.  An employer should be able to schedule work if they know when the gaps are, the biggest issue isn't asking in the first year, but coming up a week before and asking for a big holiday.  My leave year runs Jan-Dec, so by the last few days of Dec the wife and I have worked out our main holidays for the next year, and the requests go in beginning Jan.  You can still keep some floating time for flexibility, and get approval in writing.

Comment: So if you feel you're going to be away a lot start talking to them about your plans NOW, when you can negotiate. Maybe you can take all (if you have leave), maybe you agree on a subset, maybe you negotiate some extra curricular hours to get the time you need (project x needs to ship a month before the Peru trip, so you agree to work an extra couple of hours a few days a week to make sure it does, and keep them sweet, it could either count to leave time, or maybe as a favour, how keen are you to go).  They shouldn't complain if you are going above and beyond and let them know in good time.